# I appear to have died and gone to Hell. How do I get out?

Tags: glitch-2011

I forgot to eat for a while, died, and now I'm in Hell. Food turns to ash in my mouth, drink fails to quench my thirst. There's grapes around, but I can't do anything but squish them. What do I do?

Comment: I vote for the title "How do I get out of Hell?".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You squish eleven grapes, then you come back from where you died.
To squish grapes you stand near them, press ENTER, and then select "Squish".

**But wait!** Instead of squishing grapes, go right and drop down the hole. You will enter a new area. Now you can use the map, and visit all the "streets" in Nakara. Once you do this you will get a badge :D

[Source](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Hell)